# Cannot see stages times in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

As you can see from the image below, even if the build #5 terminates correctly, I cannot see the elapsed time for each stage.

[image]

The only thing that I did in the pipeline was to remove old builds with the following code (inserted in URL/script):

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME)
item.builds.each() { build ->
  build.delete()
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```

Comment: If you want to delete builds, just check discard builds check box and keep Max builds as 1...then you wont need the above piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create another pipeline, create a stage with a `print` inside and do a number of fake builds. Then, I ran the script that I posted in the answer and when I tried to do another build the stage view was empty. Then, I restarted Jenkins and now I can see the stage view.

Answer (score 0):

This might not help fully, but what happens if you go to Blue Ocean?

There's an "Open Blue Ocean" button in the left-hand menu which should take you to the pipeline view in Blue Ocean.

I find that the old UI is somewhat buggy regarding the pipelines and stage displays.

Comment: In the "Open Blue Ocean" interface, I can see the stages. It works fine, however, I still no have nothing in the "Stage view"

Comment: If you go to the Jenkins log in /var/log/jenkins.log, on the master server, do you see any errors or exceptions?